# Modbus master arduino code is throwing weird errors on upload

Tags: rs485, modbus

I am using the following https://code.google.com/p/simple-modbus/ arduino master library code. In order to communicate with my industrial drive.

All seems right but I am getting some weird errors. I am using the arduino master code as it is. With just the difference in modbus_construct.

Here is the error I am getting

```
 This report would have more information with
 "Show verbose output during compilation"


enabled in File > Preferences.
Arduino: 1.0.6 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"
In file included from SimpleModbusMasterArduino.ino:29:

C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:131: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
In file included from C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:28,
                 from C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:215,
                 from SimpleModbusMasterArduino.ino:29:
C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Stream.h:57: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
In file included from SimpleModbusMasterArduino.ino:29:
C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:222: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
SimpleModbusMasterArduino:37: error: 'Packet' does not name a type
SimpleModbusMasterArduino.ino: In function 'void setup()':
SimpleModbusMasterArduino:45: error: 'packets' was not declared in this scope
SimpleModbusMasterArduino:45: error: 'READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS' was not declared in this scope
SimpleModbusMasterArduino:45: error: 'modbus_construct' was not declared in this scope
```

SimpleModbusMasterArduino:49: error: 'modbus_configure' was not declared in this scope SimpleModbusMasterArduino.ino: In function 'void loop()': SimpleModbusMasterArduino:56: error: 'modbus_update' was not declared in this scope

Here is my code:

```
#include <SimpleModbusMaster.h>

/*
   The example will use packet1 to read a register from address 0 (the adc ch0 value)
   from the arduino slave (id=1). It will then use this value to adjust the brightness
   of an led on pin 9 using PWM.
   It will then use packet2 to write a register (its own adc ch0 value) to address 1 
   on the arduino slave (id=1) adjusting the brightness of an led on pin 9 using PWM.
*/

//////////////////// Port information ///////////////////
#define baud 115200
#define timeout 1000
#define polling 200 // the scan rate
#define retry_count 10

// used to toggle the receive/transmit pin on the driver
#define TxEnablePin 2 
#define LED 13


// The total amount of available memory on the master to store data
#define TOTAL_NO_OF_REGISTERS 8
#define TOTAL_NO_OF_CONSTANTS 1

// This is the easiest way to create new packets
// Add as many as you want. TOTAL_NO_OF_PACKETS
// is automatically updated.
enum
{
  PACKET1,
  //PACKET2,
  TOTAL_NO_OF_PACKETS // leave this last entry
};

// Create an array of Packets to be configured
Packet packets[TOTAL_NO_OF_PACKETS];

// Masters register array
unsigned int regs[TOTAL_NO_OF_REGISTERS];

void setup()
{
  // Initialize each packet
  modbus_construct(&packets[PACKET1], 1, READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0x3000, 8, 0);
  //modbus_construct(&packets[PACKET2], 2, READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0x3000, 8, 16);

  // Initialize the Modbus Finite State Machine
  modbus_configure(&Serial, baud, SERIAL_8N2, timeout, polling, retry_count, TxEnablePin, packets, TOTAL_NO_OF_PACKETS, regs);

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  modbus_update();
  Serial.println(regs[0]);
  //regs[0] = analogRead(0); // update data to be written to arduino slave

  //analogWrite(LED, regs[0]>>2); // constrain adc value from the arduino slave to 255
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you define constants, such as `timeout`, which are [widely used](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h) in Arduino library as parameter names. After preprocessing your definitions, correct code in "Arduino.h" such as

```
unsigned long pulseIn(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, unsigned long timeout);
```

becomes

```
unsigned long pulseIn(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, unsigned long 1000);
```

No wonder the latter line fails to compile.

You will need to find unique names for your defines, or use constant variables instead.